# laravel 5.1 character error request

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, xampp, laravel-5.1

I have a problem when I request the name of the input text form: My $request->input('name'); return the text with a character error.

Artist name: Aláfia

Blade template:

```
<form action="artist" method="POST" name="form-artist" id="form-artist" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
   <input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
return $request->input('name');
```

Result: AlÃ¡fia

The charset of the file and html is correct (utf-8).
Someone can help me?

Comment: What's the type and Collation of your MySql DB ?
Try to edit them to : 
Type : InnoDB
Collation : utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: But the problem is when I get the result of the request on the Controller before I put the result in the MySql DB, and the collation of the DB is utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: Add the attribute `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in the `<form...>` tag.